# Eclipse not giving me variable name suggestions

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

well I've seen in Tips & Tricks of Eclipse that it's possible to get a variable name generated by eclipse by clicking Ctrl + Space. However I'm getting empty suggestions. Fors instance I'm typing this and click ctrl + space:

> private Color

And I am supposed to get some name suggestions on it? All I'm getting is an empty list of suggestions. So what's turned off? Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: do it doesn't generate names. it only works after you have created some variables. you type the first letter/letters and when you click ctrl + space you get a list of all the variables that start with that letter/letters. it's an auto-complete tool...

Comment: check the settings : Windows > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > <>

Comment: did you find a solution? could you posted it?... the answers don't really solve the problem

Answer (score 15):

I believe you are trying to get variable name e.g. `color` after `private Color` where `Color` is you class i.e. `private Color color`.  I see that working in my eclipse.

To verify your settings, go to below settings and verify as they look good to you.

```
    Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor ->Content Assist
```

and

```
    Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor ->Content Assist -> Advanced
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking for, however it doesn't seem to work. I tried selecting all of those things in Content Assist, but they don't generate that "color" for me and don't suggest it...

Comment: In `advanced` screen, do you see proposals being listed? If yes, are they selected?

Comment: Precisely, you want to check the "Java Type Proposals" to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 15):

This is the default behavior after entering a Java type and a space, and then pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to activate auto-complete. For example, if you enter:

```
private Color
```

then activate auto-complete it will suggest some variable names for you.

An easier way than having to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> all the time is to change the characters which automatically activate auto-complete. I find it very useful to have all characters which could possible be variable names to activate auto-complete. Try having `._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` as `Auto activation triggers for Java` found in Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist:

[image: Screen shot of the Content Assist settings]

This way you can achieve how Visual Studio handles auto-complete.

Comment: Answer looks useful, but in 'C/C++' perspective is impossible to bind with an arbitrary list of characters, is there a way to do it anyway?

Answer (score 9):

Goto Window -> preferences -> java -> Editor -> content Assist ->Advances -> Select all the check boxes. DONE :)

Answer (score 2):

`private`? It looks like you're creating something new.. eclipse cannot suggest in this case.

Autocomplete is for existing variables/functions/classes/etc.

Answer (score 2):

I tried them one after the other and found out that the correct one is:

`Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor ->Content Assist -> Advanced`: check `Word Proposals`

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, it can get a variable name that you **already** made.

For example,

```
int awesomeVariable;
awesomeVariable = 50;

int superVariable;
superVariable =
```

If I press Ctrl + Space after that =, it would generate some things that it could fill in. For example, it might suggest awesomeVariable. Basically, it doesn't generate a name for you, it just auto-completes with things you have already created.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + Space is maybe shortcuts of IM, so it is covered, I suggest you change the shortcuts of this function, for example: Alt + /,

if you don't know how to change shortcuts, please see the following steps:

1. click Ctrl + Alt + L twice,
2. find "Content Assist",
3. change Binding value to you like shortcuts(cannot same the other shortcuts),
4. click Apply button.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones time and help. :)

I finally found it and the answer to this was that in my case the "java.awt.Color" wasn't imported and eclipse doesn't work on this one if it's not imported.

So it does suggest the name for you if your file had imported the class already, but if it hadn't it won't work.

I guess it makes the whole function pretty useless, but unfortunately that's how eclipse works. :/

Answer (score 0):

it just suggesting you can also declare the variable by that name..it just helping you because it was a tool write..nothing to worry about that..you can give your own name as you like kk..

import Color Class to your class: import java.awt.Color;